# Spring Boot 1.5.3 transitive dependency not resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I have updated to Spring Boot 1.5.3 and as part of upgrade I have replaced `spring-boot-starter-ws.jar` to `spring-boot-starter-web-services.jar` in my `pom.xml`. But I am having issue with one of the transitive dependency `spring-ws-core.jar`. Below is the screenshot

[image]

Following is the dependency hierarchy

[image]

Don't know why it is not able to find the classes of this dependency. Any suggestions?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for SpringDispatcher Servlet -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for HttpInvoker -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!--
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- for Object Relational Mapping (JPA/Hibernate) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate EntityManager for JPA (implementation) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CXF for REST and Webservices -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web Sockets -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>config/application.properties</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: show your pom.xml

Comment: I just downloaded the `spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar` file, and it contains the `org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/method/MethodReturnValueHandler.class` file. Perhaps your file was incorrectly downloaded?

Comment: @Andreas It is there in my dependencies also, but it is no getting picked from the classpath.

Comment: For starters cleanup your pom. You are using starters so there is no need to declare the individual dependencies again (that is the whole point of the starters). Also your setup is flawed remove the jar plugin from the configuration and you should be using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to have a proper executable jar (or war) created.

Answer (score 0):

If your company policy does not prevent you from defining `<parent>` then you can add:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

The effect will be that your POM will have a parent [`spring-boot-starter-parent`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml) which reference the [`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) which defines common dependencies and their associated versions.

So the following will be automatically added for you:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

where `spring-ws.version` is defined as:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <spring-ws.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

**Documentation:** is available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven).

If you are not allowed to set a `<parent>` then you can follow [these instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent).